# jquery ui checkbox becomes tiny when setting text

Tags: jquery-ui

Anyone know how to change the text on a `checkbox` and have the size of the `checkbox` scale appropriately?

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/szwz2L2m/

`html` ..

```
<input id="audioCheckbox" type="checkbox" />
<label id="audioCheckboxText" for="audioCheckbox">Enabled</label>
```

`js` ..

```
$(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").button();

    $("#audioCheckbox").click(function (e) {

        if (this.checked) {
            $("#audioCheckboxText").text('Enabled');
        } else {
            $("#audioCheckboxText").text('Disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `.html()` of the label, not the `.text()`:

```
$(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").button();
    $("#audioCheckbox").click(function (e) {
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#audioCheckboxText").html('<span class="ui-button-text">Enabled</span>');
        } else {
            $("#audioCheckboxText").html('<span class="ui-button-text">Disabled</span>');
        }
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/szwz2L2m/1/)**